# How to remove time from date? (Python)

Tags: python, date, datetime

I'm new to Python and programming in general. I was wondering, how would I remove the time form a date?
Here is my code:

```
import datetime
currentDate = datetime.date.today()

userInput = input("Please enter your birth date? (dd/mm/yyyy) )")
birthdate = datetime.datetime.strptime(userInput, "%d/%m/%Y").date()

days = birthdate - currentDate
print('You were born ' +str(days), 'ago')
```

At the moment, if I typed in my birth date which is 14/10/1996, it outputs "You were born 6806 days, 00:00:00 ago." and I want it to just output the date so it would end up like this "You were born 6806 days ago."

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: `days = (birthdate - currentDate).days`

Comment: Wouldn't it be days =  (currentDate - birthdata).days as well instead of the other way around?

Answer (score 2):

`days` is a [`timedelta`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#timedelta-objects) object, and you can directly access its `days` component:

```
>>> days.days # -6806
```

Answer (score 1):

What you're actually asking to do is remove the time from the `__str__` of a `timedelta` object, not a datetime object. The only way to do this is build your own string - `timedelta`'s output format is not configurable.

```
print('You were born {} days ago'.format(days.days))
```

Comment: While this could print _"You were born 1 days ago"_ given the wrong input, that's probably not an issue for your target users